# Add “New Folder” button to datasource picker

Tags: experience-editor, datasource

I'd like to enable content editors to better structure their local datasources in the Sitecore Editor when using the experience editor to select datasources for renderings.

I'd like them to be able to create a new folder underneath which ever item they have selected in the tree that is show in the dialogue.

This might work by right click and pressing "add new folder", or a new button in the left hand pane which says "Add folder under selected item".

Could anyone point me in the right direction to how I might achieve this? Image attached for better context.

[image]

Comment: I have first misread your question, that's why I have removed my answer

Comment: Would you like to have always same set of subfolders under "Local Content"? If yes, creating branch template for "Local Content" template would be an option

Comment: As you are using Habitat Local Datasources module, I would extend it with your custom subfolders and put some logic there

Comment: Crossposting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037253/add-new-folder-button-to-datasource-picker-in-sitecore

Answer (score 2):

By default this SPEAK dialog sits under:
`sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\SelectRenderingDatasource\SelectRenderingDatasource.xml`.

You'll need to override this dialog and add your custom button and functionality. Best to add a new file under `\sitecore\shell\override\Applications\Dialogs\SelectRenderingDatasource` with your custom xml/css.

The `CodeBeside` tag is where you map the `.xml` to your `.cs` class. If you have SXA, you can see how they have overridden it and added a search button.

Comment: Thanks josedbaez. Upon looking at the code behind, it looks like overriding that would involve taking much of the logic for that dialogue and bringing it into my solution's code base, which would over time become a maintenance and upgrade issue. As the logic for all the dialogue buttons are intertwined in the methods of the code behind. I have to hand the project on to other developers at some point and adding the button seems more of a hack than an extension. Probably better to get content editors to add the folders via the standard content editor tree for now.